# Subtracting one day for date when time is between midnight and 6 am - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, case, where-clause

I am trying to do a `CASE WHEN` statement where the date is changed to one day prior for timestamps after midnight and before 6 am. My company bases work days on 6 am to 6 am so I want to roll anything that happens between midnight and 6 am to show as instances of the previous day. Whenever attempting to run this it gives me the following error, but I can't figure out how to fix it. I've tried taking the `INTERVAL` part off, `TRUNC` the date and nothing I can think of is working.

```
ORA-30081: invalid data type for datetime/interval arithmetic
30081. 00000 -  "invalid data type for datetime/interval arithmetic"
*Cause:    The data types of the operands are not valid for datetime/interval
           arithmetic.
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 104
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(ADJUSTMENTTIME, 'HH24') BETWEEN 00 AND 06 THEN TO_CHAR(ADJUSTMENTTIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD') - INTERVAL '1' DAY
  ELSE TO_CHAR(ADJUSTMENTTIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  END AS ADJ_DATE, 
CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(ADJUSTMENTTIME, 'HH24') BETWEEN 06 AND 17 THEN ' DAYS' 
  ELSE ' NIGHTS'
  END AS ADJUSTMENTHOUR, SUM(ADJUSTEDAMOUNT) AS ADJ_QTY
From
*DATASOURCE*
WHERE
DESTINATIONSTATUS = 'RIP' AND
ADJUSTMENTTIME BETWEEN '05-Aug-20 06.00.00.000000000 AM' AND '06-Aug-20 06.00.00.000000000 AM'
GROUP BY ADJUSTMENTTIME
```

Comment: It seems the error is caused by the fact you try to compare a string after `TO_CHAR` with numbers in `BETWEEN 00 AND 06`. Use [`EXTRACT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm#SQLRF00639) function to get a number of hours and then it should compare with numbers just fine

Answer (score 1):

It is simpler to substract 6 hours from the date beforehand:

```
select 
    to_char(adjustmenttime - interval '6' hour, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as adj_date,
    case when to_char(adjustmenttime, 'hh24') between '06' and '17'
        then 'days'
        else 'nights'
    end as adj_hour,
    sum(adjustmentamount) adj_amount
from datasource
where 
    destinationstatus = 'RIP'
    and adjustmenttime >= timestamp '2020-08-05 06:00:00'
    and adjustmenttime < timestamp '2020-08-06 06:00:00'
group by 1, 2
```